# Remove field from a nested array of json object having key values pairs using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Remove id field from the nested array of json object having key values pairs (empval) using pyspark

**Input**

```
+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| empno    | empcode| empval                                                                                                   |
+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| employee1| 100DRE | [{"id": "123", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}, {"id": "234", "key1": "te", "key2": "value2"}, {"id": "345", "key1": "grtregert", "key2": "value2"}] |
+----------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected output**

```
+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| empno    | empcode| newColumn                                                                                                           |
+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| employee1| 100DRE | [{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}, {"key1": "te", "key2": "value2"}, {"key1": "grtregert", "key2": "value2"}]|
+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple,

- Use the `from_json` function & provide the required schema `array<struct<key1: string, key2: string>>`.
- Spark will extract columns from the JSON using the specified schema.
- Use `to_json` function to convert the data back into a JSON as your expected output.

```
df.show(False)
+---------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|empno    |empcode|empval                                                                                                                                                  |
+---------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|employee1|100DRE |[{"id": "123", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}, {"id": "234", "key1": "te", "key2": "value2"}, {"id": "345", "key1": "grtregert", "key2": "value2"}]|
+---------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
df
.selectExpr(
   "empno", 
   "empcode", 
   "to_json(from_json(empval, 'array<struct<key1: string, key2: string>>')) AS newColumn"
)
.show(False)
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|empno    |empcode|newColumn                                                                                             |
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|employee1|100DRE |[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"te","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"grtregert","key2":"value2"}]|
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```